# what value series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{\lfloor rp \rfloor}{2^r}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have been wondering about series of $$S=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{\lfloor rp \rfloor}{2^r}$$ where p is a constant positive real number and $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is floor function.

I know it converges because $ \frac{\lfloor rp \rfloor}{2^r}\leq \frac{ rp }{2^r}$ where $r$ is positive integer and $p$ is constant positive real number; since series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{rp}{2^r}$ is a A.G.P series with common ratio less than $1$, the given series converges.

But to what value our series $S$ converges? How to find it? What is the method?

Actually I have to find convergence value for $p=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Also what would happen if it was ceiling function and nearest integer function??

I couldn't find any method to find value of convergence,any hint would be appreciable,thanks

Comment: Are you interested in the value of the infinite series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \lfloor rp\rfloor/2^r$? This seems likely, since you're talking about convergence.

Comment: Yes I want to know the method and to know the convergence value when p=$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect there is a simple answer to this question? In general, sums containing floor-brackets tend to be very difficult.

Comment: Actually I was doing a question with nearest integer function and golden ratio,so I was wondering what would happen if it was floor function.besides I just want to know what is the general method for this type of question

Comment: It might help to use $\lfloor rp\rfloor = rp - \frac12 + \frac1\pi \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin 2\pi krp}k$ (for irrational $p$... for rational $p$, other techniques must be used).

Answer (score 1):

As a start,
based on similar sums
I vaguely recall,
write,
where
$\{z\}$
is the fractional part of $z$,

$\begin{array}\\
S_n
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\lfloor rp \rfloor}{2^r}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{rp-\{rp\}}{2^r}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{rp}{2^r}-\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\{rp\}}{2^r}\\
&=p\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{r}{2^r}-\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\{rp\}}{2^r}\\
&= pU_n - V_n
\end{array}
$

$U_n$ is a standard sum.

For $V_n$,
if you look at
the binary representation of $p$,
you might be able to see
when that
fractional part changes.

That's all I can think of for now.

Comment: How to find $V_n$ for $p=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: Don't know. Maybe look at the continued fraction. Probably something in the Fibonacci Quarterly.